# Sorting an array of partially sorted primitive integers in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, integer

The array in question may hold any integer which equals or is bigger than zero and the numbers are unique. The numbers have to be in ascending order.

The array's size will usually be less than 100.
Most of the array is already sorted. By most I mean on avarage atleast 90% of it.

I've found this [implementation of TimSort](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~martin/webrevs/openjdk7/timsort/raw_files/new/src/share/classes/java/util/TimSort.java) but it is not for primitive values. Autoboxing would cause a lot of overhead.

Performance is most crucial as the sorting-algorithm will be called many times.

Comment: Just write your own version of the TimSort algorithm that is adapted to integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-):

```
int[] array = /* something */;
Arrays.sort(array);
```

Being only one line, this is (obviously) both extremely simple to use and very readable. That should be your #1 priority when writing code. It's also going to be pretty darn fast, because the writers of the standard library have put a lot of effort into performance, *particularly* relating to sorting algorithms.

The only situation in which you should *not* use `Arrays.sort` is if you've almost entirely finished your system, profiled it carefully, and determined that the part of the code that sorts your array is the bottleneck. Even then, you still might not be able to write your own sorting algorithm that performs noticeably better.

Comment: So I've looked into it and it seems that since Java 8, the SL no longer uses TimSort for sorting primitive arrays. The TimSort I found earlier (link in the question), I've adjusted it work with only on integer arrays and to always sort them in ascending order. Since the system will be used exclusively in games, performance is crucial. I've read that TimSort has a much better time complexity for partially sorted arrays, substantially lower than O(n log(n)). And for small arrays, it uses insertion sort, which is (as i've read) faster than quicksort (on small arrays).

Comment: @BendegúzNagy Great! But as I've said, unless you've already made sure that this is the bottleneck of your program, you're probably wasting your time. I understand that performance in games is crucial, etc., but unless you've actually profiled it and made sure that it *really makes a difference*, there's not much point. As I'm sure you've already heard a thousand times, premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Well yes it is, but since the skeleton of the system is compelete, and because it is a framework (Entity-Component System), optimizing it will not cause games to be less readable, as the interface through which it is used remains the same.

Comment: @BendegúzNagy OK. Good luck on your project!

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by "almost sorted". [Insertion Sort](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/insertion-sort) is a very efficient algorithm if the array is nearly sorted (linear complexity when it is sorted), but the performance can vary depending on whether the outliers are close or far from their final sorted position. For example, `[1,2,3,4,6,5,7,8,9]` will be slightly faster to sort than `[1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2]`.

Comment: An array of 100 integers at about 400 bytes will fit into an L1 CPU cache (typically 32kb). 
Since sorting of `ints` is completely dominated by memory access, I doubt that you will see an application-significant difference between any sensible sorting implementation.